# Asp.net and Sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

verify user name and password in login page using asp.net with sql server.
But problem is that when i enter the correct data ..go to the error page, not go to the welcom page..

```
  using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Configuration;

    namespace WebApplication21

    {
        public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
           protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

             SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from 'user_insert' where username = @username and password = @password,con");
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox1.Text);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox2.Text);
          SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
          DataTable dt = new DataTable();
          da.Fill(dt);

          if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
          {
              Response.Redirect("Welcom.aspx");
          }
          else
          {
              Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");
          }

    }
```

And Connection String in web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="dbconnection" connectionString="Data Source=Ali-PC;Initial Catalog=LogIn;Integrated Security=True"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: What have you set cmd.CommandText to? Where are you defining cmd?

Comment: you r not setting the command to execute..sqlcommand cmd = new sqlcommand("select * from 'your table' where username = username and password = @password,con);

Comment: plain-text passwords make sad. It's wrong. Passwords must be stored hashed and salted.

Answer (score 1):

Execute the query and you will get the result in your data table use below code instead of yours:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from 'user_insert' where username = @username and password = @password,con");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox2.Text);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
da.Fill(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the sql command to execute in your code you are executing

`SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);` but no where you assign any sql command to cmd

try like this and check the result

```
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
    (@"select * from 'your table' where username = @username and password = @password",con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox1.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox2.Text);

          DataTable dt = new DataTable();
          dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
```